# Invoking Python's Idle on Ubuntu v15 terminal

Tags: python

I have Python3 preinstalled on Ubuntu v15. But when I try to open the Idle at the terminal by typing `Idle` at the command promt, I get "NameError: name 'Idle' is not define

Comment: `idle` is not a Python command, so typing it in Python gives you an error message, as you have discovered.

Comment: Are you at the linux shell command prompt or in the python shell? You could open a new terminal, try idle, then copy the entire session here so we can see for sure.

Comment: At the linux shell command promt, I typed 'idle' and I get 'The program 'idle' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudu apt- get install idle

Comment: Are you able to install idle with that command?

Answer (score 1):

**Install idle for Python 3**:

```
sudo apt-get install idle3
```

to launch idle3:
it can be open from :

1. Ubuntu software menu
2. type idle3 on the command line

**for Python2 use:**

```
sudo apt-get install idle
```